# Scanner not reading .txt

Tags: java

I Have an a self checkout which exports the all items purchased to a .txt file upon printing a receipt.

```
public void printReceipt()
{   
    // \t - creates tabs for alignment
    String construct = String.format("%-25s %-8s %-8s %-10s %-10s", "Name", "ID", "Price", "Quantity", "Weight");
    infoField.append(construct + "\n");
    ArrayList<String> exportText = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Item itm : scan) 
    {
        String output = String.format("%-25s %-8s %-8s %-12s %-12s", itm.name, itm.Id, itm.price, itm.getCount(), itm.getWeight());
        infoField.append(output + "\n");
        String itmType = "";
        if (itm instanceof BarcodeItem)
            {
                itmType = "barcode";
                exportText.add(itmType+"-"+itm.name+"-"+itm.Id+"-"+itm.price+"-"+itm.getBarcode()+"-");
            }
        else if (itm instanceof CountedItem)
            {
                itmType = "counted";
                exportText.add(itmType+"-"+itm.name+"-"+itm.Id+"-"+itm.price+"-"+itm.getCount()+"-");
            }
        else if (itm instanceof WeightedItem)
            {
                itmType = "weighted";
                exportText.add(itmType+"-"+itm.name+"-"+itm.Id+"-"+itm.price+"-"+itm.getWeight()+"-");
            }    
    }
    transId++;
    outputStream.println(exportText+"-"+transId);
    outputStream.close();
}
```

After this is done, I have the .txt file imported using a scanner and using a delimiter separating each chunk and parsing it into its original data type.

Unfortunately in my load text method the debugger is showing String name; is not being initialised and I dont understand why?

```
public void loadText() throws IOException
{
    while(reader.hasNext())
    {
        String type = reader.next();
        String name = reader.next();
        int id = Integer.parseInt(reader.next());
        double price = Double.parseDouble(reader.next());

        if (type.equals("barcode"))
        {
          String  barcode = reader.next();
          Item itm = new BarcodeItem(id, name, price, barcode);
         // aList.addElement(itm.toString());
          System.out.println("Item has been added");
        }
        else if (type.equals("counted"))
        {
           double count = Double.parseDouble(reader.next());
           Item itm = new CountedItem(id, name, price, count);
          // aList.addElement(itm.toString());
           System.out.println("Item has been added");
        }
        else if (type.equals("weighted"))
        {
            double weight = Double.parseDouble(reader.next());
            Item itm = new WeightedItem(id, name, price, weight);
           // aList.addElement(itm.toString());
            System.out.println("Item has been added");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No file found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a problem reading a file, don't show us code that writes the file using data we don't have. **Show us the file itself**, so we know what you are trying to read. Maybe you should look at the file yourself, because I don't think it contains what you think it does.

Comment: Also, you need to show how `reader` is created, e.g. what delimiter is it using?

Comment: The file itself is dynamic and always changing with a new transaction. But an example of what it looks like is: 

Ice cream-3-4.0-0.0-0.0-001-1001

I've used a delimiter to separate at the "-", thanks for your feedback.